# Find duplicates out of multiple columns

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a tricky sql problem. Let me qive you an example

```
ID1   Name     Name2   Name3   Name4

100   Albert   Kevin   Jon     Alex
101   Albert   Jon     Kevin   Alex
102   Albert   Georg   Alex    Babera
103   Albert   Stefany
```

Lets say ID1 gives me a project ID and Name is the main person (Albert). Name2-4 are subgroups of people who worked with Albert. Now I want to count matches between this subgroups. First I want to know exact matches. For example between 100 and 101.
Second is it possible to count how many names matches? Like one match between 101 and 100.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The schema is designed to make that unbearably hard.  Normalize the data and it will be easier (not easy, but easier).

Comment: You are not clear, The fact that in your example, (100 to 101) you specify that there is only *one* match implies that you want the position of the name to be considered as well as the value (cause all three names are in both rows somewhere).  Can you clarify what the significance of the columns in this schema mean, and what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create a new ID, lets say ID2 which will have the same vlaue for the rows 100 and 101 and different for 102 and 103

Comment: Or should I reshape my data in lets say only on name and then columns for all the projects ID1 are people in.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is long and not bulletproof but it kind of does the job.

```
WITH source_t AS
(
        SELECT 100 id, 'Albert' name, 'Kevin'  name2, 'Jon' name3, 'Alex' name4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 101,    'Albert',      'Jon',          'Kevin',     'Alex'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 102,    'Albert',      'Georg',        'Alex',      'Babera'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT 103,    'Albert',      'Stefany',      NULL,         NULL        FROM DUAL
)
, tab_1 AS
(
        SELECT id, name, name2 FROM source_t UNION ALL
        SELECT id, name, name3 FROM source_t UNION ALL
        SELECT id, name, name4 FROM source_t
)
, tab_2 AS
(
        SELECT  id
        ,       name
        ,       name2
        ,       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, name ORDER BY name2) AS r_number
        FROM    tab_1
)
, tab_3 AS
(
        SELECT  id
        ,       name
        ,       MAX(CASE WHEN r_number = 1 THEN name2 END) AS name2
        ,       MAX(CASE WHEN r_number = 2 THEN name2 END) AS name3
        ,       MAX(CASE WHEN r_number = 3 THEN name2 END) AS name4
        FROM    tab_2
        GROUP   BY
                id
        ,       name
)
SELECT  tab_3.id
,       tab_3.name
,       tab_3.name2
,       tab_3.name3
,       tab_3.name4
,       tab_4.n_count
FROM    tab_3
LEFT    JOIN
(
        SELECT  name
        ,       name2
        ,       name3
        ,       name4
        ,       COUNT(1) AS n_count
        FROM    tab_3
        GROUP   BY
                name
        ,       name2
        ,       name3
        ,       name4
)  tab_4
ON      tab_3.name  = tab_4.name
and     NVL(tab_3.name2, 'NULL') = NVL(tab_4.name2, 'NULL')
and     NVL(tab_3.name3, 'NULL') = NVL(tab_4.name3, 'NULL')
and     NVL(tab_3.name4, 'NULL') = NVL(tab_4.name4, 'NULL')
;
/*
102 Albert  Alex    Babera  Georg   1
103 Albert  Stefany NULL    NULL    1
101 Albert  Alex    Jon     Kevin   2
100 Albert  Alex    Jon     Kevin   2
*/
```